# How to install face-recognition without having to install Visual Studio C++

Tags: python, c++, face-recognition

I need to install face-recognition on windows without having to install Visual Studio C++, is there any way to do this? The problem is that it depends on the dlib library and this depends on having Visual C++ installed.

Comment: That's not a lot of context for a good question. Note that general software install questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems that `dlib` is only distributed as [source code](https://pypi.org/project/dlib/19.22.0/#files). As a result, you will need to compile it on your own. This means that you will need Visual Studio C++ installed, but you can uninstall it afterwords unless you need to update `dlib` frequently. If you need instructions, you can find them [here](http://dlib.net/compile.html).

Comment: And isn't it possible to create a dlib build and make it public for download? I mean, I compile and distribute the dlib python library so that other people can download it directly.

Comment: If this can be done, then if someone can publish it in a cloud or something, so I can download it, because right now I have very little space on the machine and it is not possible for me to install all Visual Studio together with Visual C++.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Anaconda for installing and using that package.
first, install Anaconda from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download). After that, you can create a new conda environment or use base (default environment) then use the following command in the Anaconda prompt `conda install -c conda-forge face_recognition`. In that situation, you can have face recognition without installing Visual Studio C++.